# system.windows.forms.richtextbox does not contain document in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Watch this image:

[image]

```
TextRange tr = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
```

> Error `system.windows.forms.richtextbox` does not contain document

Answer (score 1):

It is like your error message already tries to tell you.

The `RichTextBox` class definition in `WinForms` doesn't contain a property Document.

You could assign your content to the `richTextBox1.text` property or use `richTextBox1.LoadFile()`. Please have a look at the MSDN documentation:
[RichTextBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)